# Mauvais français ou bon anglais ?

Tags: discussion, language

Il y a déjà beaucoup de questions sur *French Language meta* au sujet de la langue propre des questions, et (je pense que) le consensus est une préférence pour les questions rédigées en français, mais vous acceptez les questions en anglais quand même.

Quand j'écris des questions en français il y a beaucoup d'erreurs et pour chaque question, il faut que quelqu'un l'édite, parfois avec beaucoup d'effort. Est-ce que ça vaut la peine, ou est-ce que vous préféreriez les questions en anglais quand l'écrivain ne connait pas bien le français.

---

There are many questions on *French Language meta* over the subject of which language questions should appear in. I think your consensus is that, while questions in French are preferable, questions in English should also be accepted. (Perhaps in any other language too.)

When I write questions in French, there are many errors in each question, and someone else has to edit it, sometimes with a lot of work. Is this worth it, or is it annoying — would you prefer questions in English when the writer does not know a lot of French?

Comment: Moi aussi je ne parle pas bien français, ils il y plusieurs raisons qui me convainquent que ce soit sage de poser mes questions en français : 
Tout d'abord, l’anglais n’est pas ma langue maternelle donc si je pratique cette langue, je fais également des fautes. 
Deuxièmement, je ne pense pas que ce soit dur de retirer les fautes d’un locuteur de l’étranger, s’il s’exprime clairement. Tant mieux si on ajoute une traduction comme vous faîtes ici.
Troisièmement, je dois la moitié de la connaissance que je rassemble ici de mes questions corrigées.

Comment: Voir aussi [Should the site help really tell those learning French to ask in French?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/445/should-the-site-help-really-tell-those-learning-french-to-ask-in-french)

Answer (score 5):

Je dirais que c'est entièrement à votre discrétion.

Si vous êtes à l'aise d'écrire en français malgré les erreurs et voulez apprendre des corrections apportées à votre question par les autres utilisateurs, écrivez en français! Il n'y a pas de « correcteur attitré ». Toutes les questions et réponses du site sont modifiables par n'importe quel utilisateur. Si une personne ne désire pas corriger votre question, quelqu'un d'autre le fera avec plaisir. Même les modérateurs ne sont pas tenus de corriger les questions. Ce sont des volontaires comme nous tous qui ont parfois autre chose à faire, et c'est bien comme ça.

Si au contraire vous n'êtes pas très à l'aise d'écrire en français, que vous craignez les fautes que vous pourriez faire et que, du coup, vous ne posez pas toutes les questions que vous aimeriez poser, je vous prie d'écrire en anglais! Il n'y a aucun mal à écrire en anglais. Il est vrai que certains de nos utilisateurs, passés, présents ou futurs, n'ont pas une très bonne maîtrise de la langue de Shakespeare, mais je crois que la majorité au moins la comprenne, et certains ne se gêneront pas à répondre en français. Certaines personnes demandent même une traduction de leur réponse dans ces cas.

En fin de compte, ce qui est important, c'est que vous soyez à l'aise de poser les questions que vous voulez pour obtenir les réponses que vous cherchez. Que vous posiez vos questions en français ou en anglais, ça importe peu. Vous voulez en savoir plus sur le français, et nous voulons vous aider à apprendre. C'est tout.

---

I would say that it is entirely up to you.

If you are comfortable writing in French despite the mistakes you make and you want to learn from the edits made by other users to your post, write in French! There is no "assigned proofreader". Every question and answer is editable by any user. If one person doesn't want to correct your mistakes, someone else will be happy to do so. Even moderators are not obligated to correct questions. They're doing this on their own time and sometimes they have other things to do, and that's perfectly fine.

If, on the other hand, you are not very comfortable with writing in French, if you're worrying about the mistakes you could make and, because of it, you are not asking all the questions you'd like to, then please write in English! There is nothing wrong with writing in English. While it is true that some of our users, may they be past, present or future, don't have a very good hold on Shakespeare's tongue, I think most of them understand it, and some of them won't shy away from answering in French. A few people even ask to have their answer translated in those cases.

At the end of the day, what really matters is that you feel comfortable to ask the questions you want so that you can get the answers you are seeking. Whether you're asking in French or in English matters little. You want to learn about French, and we want to teach you about French. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

J'apprécie l'effort que les non francophones font à poser leurs questions en français, je suis certaine ne pas être la seule. Ils montrent ainsi leur motivation et ça m'incite à leur répondre plus en détails. Éditer une question pour la corriger, comme le dit @KoenraadvanDuin ce n'est pas un gros travail et tous ceux qui corrigent le font avec plaisir et dans un esprit de propager le français. Si je ne comprends pas la question je le dis et demande des précisions.
Pour ma part je préfère une question posée en français, et surtout de locuteurs non anglophones qui ne maîtrisent pas l'anglais et qui se rajoutent ainsi un filtre supplémentaire à la compréhension du français.

De plus si vous posez les questions en anglais, vous avez la plupart du temps des réponses en anglais, sans traduction en français, perdant ainsi l'occasion de progresser encore plus et d'apprendre des mots nouveaux.